# Lucene.net index directory usage in java lucene

Tags: c#, java, lucene, lucene.net

Lucene.net is a direct port of Lucene for java, so it stands to reason that i could use the index directory created by Lucene.net directly from Lucene in java, is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Lucene.Net site](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/):

> In addition to the APIs and classes
>   port to C#, the algorithm of Java
>   Lucene is ported to C# Lucene. This
>   means an index created with Java
>   Lucene is back-and-forth compatible
>   with the C# Lucene; both at reading,
>   writing and updating. In fact a Lucene
>   index can be concurrently searched and
>   updated using Java Lucene and C#
>   Lucene processes.

However, as Thilo points out in the comments, this compatibility is version-dependant; the index format may change between releases.

Comment: Be careful to match the versions, though. Lucene improve their index format from time to time and then the old version cannot read the updated index files anymore.